# How can I get two buttons and textareas from separate forms to display inline?

Tags: html, css

I've got two forms inside a larger div. Each form has a button to click on and a text area. I've added divs inside the forms to style the buttons how I like. I want the two buttons to go side by side with their corresponding text areas underneath them. "display:inline:block" does not seem to be doing it for me...

This is what they look like now.

[image]

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="window">

    <form class="sumform" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="btns btn_sum">
            <input type="submit" id="sub_sum" value="Summary Statistics"/>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="sum_spec"/>
    </form>

    <form class="histform" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="btns btn_hist">
            <input type="submit" id="sub_hist" value="Histogram"/>
        </div> 
        <input type="text" id="hist_spec"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.window {
    background-color: #fdf2e3;
    display: inline-block;    
    text-align: left;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

div.btns input {
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    width:130px;
    height:0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color:#3acb9a;
    border: none;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the  `display` property for your `form`

```
form {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/TT7BC/3/**

<sub>Remember it will display side by side if they can fit into his parent `width` so you can set fixed widths for `.window` and `form` or use in parent `white-space:nowrap` to prevent the items break in a new line</sub>